# Python Pandas takes about 25 milliseconds to use the loc[] function. How can I speed it up?

Tags: python, pandas, performance

The Python Pandas takes about 25 milliseconds to use the loc[] function. I have about 185,000 rows in the dataframe. Therefore, it takes about one and a half hours to run my program. How can I speed it up?

This is how I am using it and how I can tell how long it takes:

```
m_time = time.time()
element = dataframe.loc[(dataframe['text'] == t) & (dataframe['text1'] == t1)]
print(time.time() - m_time)
```

The terminal then prints:

```
0.026927947998046875
0.02593064308166504
0.026927709579467773
0.025930166244506836
0.026927471160888672
0.026927709579467773
0.026927947998046875
0.024932861328125
0.02593064308166504
0.02593088150024414
0.026927709579467773
0.02593088150024414
0.02593064308166504
...
```

**Edit**

Here is the entire function.  The timing statements around the dataframe `.loc[]` operation have been removed.

```
def parse_jmdict(xml_file='JMdict_e.xml', furigana_file='JmdictFurigana.json'):
    tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
    root = tree.getroot()
    c = conn.cursor()
    entries_processed = 0
    start_time = time.time()

    print("Starting parsing of {0}".format(furigana_file))
    json_file = open(furigana_file, encoding="utf-8-sig")
    json_str = json_file.read()
    furigana_list = json.loads(json_str)
    furigana_dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(furigana_list)

    print("Starting parsing of {0}".format(xml_file))

    # For every entry
    for entry in root.findall('entry'):
        entry_id = entry.find('ent_seq').text

        for k_ele in entry.findall('k_ele'):  # For every Kanji Element in an entry
            keb = k_ele.find('keb').text
            c.execute('INSERT INTO Jmdict_Kanji_Element (ENTRY_ID, VALUE) VALUES (?, ?)', (entry_id, keb))

            ke_pri = k_ele.findall('ke_pri')
            for priority in ke_pri:
                c.execute('INSERT INTO Jmdict_Priority (ENTRY_ID, VALUE, TYPE) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', (entry_id, priority.text, 'Kanji_Element'))

        for r_ele in entry.findall('r_ele'):  # For every Reading Element in an entry
            reb = r_ele.find('reb').text
            re_nokanji = r_ele.find('re_nokanji')
            re_nokanji_value = 0
            if re_nokanji is not None:
                re_nokanji_value = 1
            c.execute('INSERT INTO Jmdict_Reading_Element (ENTRY_ID, VALUE, NO_KANJI) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', (entry_id, reb, re_nokanji_value))

            c.execute('SELECT last_insert_rowid()')
            r_ele_id = c.fetchone()[0]
            for re_restr in r_ele.findall('re_restr'):
                c.execute('INSERT INTO Jmdict_Reading_Relation (ENTRY_ID, READING_ELEMENT_ID, VALUE) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', (entry_id, r_ele_id, re_restr.text))

            for k_ele in entry.findall('k_ele'):
                keb = k_ele.find('keb').text
                element_furigana = furigana_dataframe.loc[(furigana_dataframe['text'] == keb) & (furigana_dataframe['reading'] == reb)]
                try:
                    element_furigana_dict_list = element_furigana.iloc[0]["furigana"]
                    for i in range(len(element_furigana_dict_list)):
                        c.execute('INSERT INTO Jmdict_Furigana_Bottom (ENTRY_ID, READING_ELEMENT_ID, FURIGANA_PORTION_INDEX, VALUE) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', (entry_id, r_ele_id, i, element_furigana_dict_list[i]["ruby"]))
                        furigana_top = 0
                        if "rt" in element_furigana_dict_list[i].keys():
                            furigana_top = element_furigana_dict_list[i]["rt"]
                        c.execute('INSERT INTO Jmdict_Furigana_Top (ENTRY_ID, READING_ELEMENT_ID, FURIGANA_PORTION_INDEX, VALUE) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', (entry_id, r_ele_id, i, furigana_top))
                except IndexError:
                    pass

            for priority in r_ele.findall('re_pri'):
                c.execute('INSERT INTO Jmdict_Priority (ENTRY_ID, VALUE, TYPE) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', (entry_id, priority.text, 'Reading_Element'))

        for sense in entry.findall('sense'):  # For every Sense element in an entry
            c.execute('INSERT INTO Jmdict_Sense_Element (ENTRY_ID) VALUES (?)', (entry_id,))

            c.execute('SELECT last_insert_rowid()')
            sense_id = c.fetchone()[0]

            pos_list = sense.findall('pos')
            for pos in pos_list:
                c.execute('INSERT INTO Jmdict_Sense_Pos (SENSE_ID, VALUE) VALUES (?, ?)', (sense_id, pos.text))

            gloss_list = sense.findall('gloss')
            for gloss in gloss_list:
               c.execute('INSERT INTO Jmdict_Gloss (ENTRY_ID, SENSE_ID, VALUE) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', (entry_id, sense_id, gloss.text))

            misc_list = sense.findall('misc')
            for misc in misc_list:
                c.execute('INSERT INTO Jmdict_Sense_Miscellaneous (SENSE_ID, VALUE) VALUES (?, ?)', (sense_id, misc.text))

            field_list = sense.findall('field')
            for field in field_list:
                c.execute('INSERT INTO Jmdict_Sense_Field (SENSE_ID, VALUE) VALUES (?, ?)', (sense_id, field.text))

            dialect_list = sense.findall('dial')
            for dial in dialect_list:
                c.execute('INSERT INTO Jmdict_Sense_Dialect (SENSE_ID, VALUE) VALUES (?, ?)', (sense_id, dial.text))

        entries_processed += 1
        if entries_processed % 5 == 0:
            print(str(entries_processed) + " entries processed")

    conn.commit()
    print("Completed parsing of {0}".format(xml_file))
    print("Number of entries parsed: {0}".format(entries_processed))
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: Can you share more of your data and code (see: [mcve]). What are you doing with `element`? Odds are you can get rid of the `.loc[]` entirely.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Edited and added entire function

Comment: Looks like you're using a DataBase, right? Can you include some test data, whatever is necessary to run the program and reproduce the error?

Comment: Forgot to ask: Have you done any benchmarking or profiling? Is Pandas really a huge performance issue here?

Comment: Why do you think the `.loc[]` calls are taking 25 ms?  The timing in that function covers a JSON file read, printing, and database calls.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile here is my program: http://www.mediafire.com/file/xdgjq9p1y5qbelf/Python.zip/file. I am a major beginner when it comes to any sort of programming in general so I am not sure what you mean or know how to do that. All I know is that single line takes about 25ms, and I run that line about 185000 times

Comment: @NicholasM Which timing are you referring to? The first code snippet is fine, no?

Comment: @AdenDiamond Have you run the program to completion?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I have run the program twice before, and it did indeed take about  one and a half hours

Comment: @AdenDiamond, the timing lines in your actual function are on the fifth line and the last line of a 150-line function. Are you saying you’re separately timing just that single line alone somewhere else?

Comment: @AdenDiamond Can we get some data, some information about your database, etc?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile There is an XML file and a JSON file in the zip folder. The CreateTables.py file creates a SQLite3 database and the ParseXMLtoSQL.py file uses the XML and JSON files to populate the database created by CreateTables.py.

Comment: @NicholasM the timing lines from the first code snippet were removed. Those lines are timing the whole function

Comment: @AdenDiamond If you want help with performance, we're going to need _way_ more detail than that... First, in order to diagnose the problem, second, because a full refactor/rewrite may be necessary.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile The program rarely needs to be run anyway, so it probably isn't worth my time if it needs a full rewrite. I was just wondering if there was a faster way to write the line in the first snippet. Sorry to bother you.

Comment: @AdenDiamond Even if you run it rarely, it could be a fantastic learning opportunity! I can see a few areas I would like to investigate, at the DB level, the XML parsing, etc., but ultimately it's up to you.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Ok... But there is something you should know. I downloaded this: https://github.com/luke-c/Japanese-Dictionary-Parser and edited so that the database also contains data from a JSON file (the furigana). The original files don't use pandas.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202956/discussion-between-aden-diamond-and-alexander-cecile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can improve the execution time of that line by setting an index, rather than using a boolean series lookup.

Here is a snippet from the function:

```
element_furigana = furigana_dataframe.loc[(furigana_dataframe['text'] == keb) & 
                                          (furigana_dataframe['reading'] == reb)]
element_furigana_dict_list = element_furigana.iloc[0]["furigana"]
```

This is doing much more work than it needs to:  it is filtering all columns of the entire dataframe, when it really needs one column value from the first (only?) row matching those criteria.

Since there is no reproducible way to test this, I generated some test data:

```
import itertools
import string

import pandas

records = itertools.product(*[string.ascii_lowercase]*3, string.digits)
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_records([(''.join(t[0:2]), ''.join(t[2:4]), hash(t)) 
                                    for t in records],
                                   columns=['text', 'reading', 'furigana'])
```

`df.shape` is `(175760, 3)`, which is close to your dataframe (by design).

Printing the head and tail gives:

```
       text reading             furigana
0        aa      a0 -5422069581675220239
1        aa      a1  -653727266625336176
2        aa      a2  3207829723004107725
3        aa      a3  4314664729972606463
175756   zz      z6  3818139299469014399
175757   zz      z7  4401450686737676603
175758   zz      z8  1773038865889527139
175759   zz      z9  3066148500118677746
```

There are two approaches to try:

1. the current approach, of creating a boolean mask and getting the first element of the `furigana` column; and
2. an approach in which the `text` and `reading` columns are turned into an index.

For approach 2, we create a Series like this:

```
s = df.set_index(['text', 'reading'])['furigana']
```

```
text  reading
aa    a0        -5422069581675220239
      a1         -653727266625336176
      a2         3207829723004107725
      a3         4314664729972606463
zz    z6         3818139299469014399
      z7         4401450686737676603
      z8         1773038865889527139
      z9         3066148500118677746
Name: furigana, dtype: int64
```

The results on my machine:

```
keb = 'zz'
reb = 'a4'
scope = dict(df=df, s=s, keb=keb, reb=reb)

timeit.timeit("df[(df['text'] == keb) & (df['reading'] == reb)]",
              globals=scope, number=1000)
```

Result:  `19.1124583`, or 0.19 seconds per call

```
timeit.timeit("s.loc[(keb, reb)]", globals=scope, number=1000)
```

Result:  `0.042754`, or 0.000042 seconds per call

Comment: Nice catch! I had no idea the difference in performance between the two could be so drastic.

Comment: It worked! The program finished in 53 seconds. Quite an improvement from 1.5 hours. Thanks for your help!